# Where to obtain free 15m ASTER image for New Mexico?

Tags: raster, data, erdas-imagine, ndvi, aster

I am looking for a free Advanced Spaceborne Thermal Emission and Reflection Radiometer (ASTER) image that will let me to perform NDVI for the pilot crop health/soil moisture that can go as far back ten years or so.

It needs to have:

- 15 m (meters)
- temporal
- Ten years back or so
- Perform NDVI

This will be in a small area somewhere near Albuquerque, NM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily download freely available ASTER Level 1B (at-sensor calbirated radiances) from the [USGS EarthExplorer site](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/). A simple quick search for a polygon roughly covering New Mexico returns > 100 results, but individual scenes are much smaller, so for a full cover of the state you'd have to stitch them together. [USGS Glovis](http://glovis.usgs.gov/) should have the same data, though an older interface.

[image: USGS EarthExplorer screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

The NASA Reverb site (http://reverb.echo.nasa.gov/reverb/#utf8=✓&spatial_map=satellite&spatial_type=rectangle) lists ASTER data for download.

[image]

You can take a look there for your specific study site and time.

Answer (score 1):

You can download ASTER image from the following websites

1. USGS Global Visualization Viewer (GLOVIS)
2. USGS Earth Explorer
3. University of Maryland Global Land Cover Facility (GLCF)
4. NASA Echo-Reverb
5. LP – DAAC ASTER / MODIS Data Pool (USA ASTER)